# How to summaries many different variables in a table in R

Tags: r, dataframe, multiple-columns

I have a huge table where I need to summarise many numerical columns.  Some of them have a pattern (like Var) some others not (Temperature). In the example bellow I'm interested in all columns which starts with Var and in column Temperature.
The output of the summary will be feeded into a pivot_longer
I'm wondering how can I write the code below in a better and compact way instead oflisting each variable in summaries

```
  df <- data.frame ( Var1 = sample(0:1,20,TRUE), 
               Var2 = sample(0:1,20,TRUE),
               Var3 = sample(0:1,20,TRUE), 
               Var4 = sample(0:1,20,TRUE),
               Var5 = sample(0:1,20,TRUE), 
               Var6 = sample(0:1,20,TRUE),
               Var7 = sample(0:1,20,TRUE), 
               Var8 = sample(0:1,20,TRUE),
               Var9 = sample(0:1,20,TRUE), 
               Var10 = sample(0:1,20,TRUE), 
               Pressure = sample(0:1,20,TRUE),
               Size = sample(0:1,20,TRUE),
               Temperature = sample(0:1,20,TRUE),
               Membership = rep(c("YES", "NO"), each = 2))

  df 
  df %>% 
     group_by(Membership)%>% 
     summarise( V1 =sum(Var1), V2=sum(Var2), V3 =sum(Var3), V4=sum(Var4), V5 =sum(Var5), 
  V6=sum(Var6), V7 =sum(Var7), V8=sum(Var8),V9 =sum(Var9), V10=sum(Var10), V11 = sum(Temperature) ) 
  %>% 
     pivot_longer(cols = starts_with("V"), names_to = "Types", values_to = "Freq") %>% 
      ggplot()+
      geom_bar(aes(x = Types, y = Freq), stat="identity", fill="blue", colour="black")+
      facet_wrap( ~ Membership)
```

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

summarise columns and then get data in long format

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df %>% 
  group_by(Membership) %>%
  summarise(across(c(starts_with('Var'), Temperature), sum)) %>%
  #In older version of dplyr use `summarise_at`
  #summarise_at(vars(c(starts_with('Var'), Temperature)), sum)
  pivot_longer(cols = c(starts_with("V"), Temperature), 
               names_to = "Types", values_to = "Freq")
```

Or first get data in long format and then summarise :

```
df %>% 
  group_by(Membership) %>%
  pivot_longer(cols = c(starts_with("V"), Temperature), 
               names_to = "Types", values_to = "Freq") %>%
  group_by(Membership, Types) %>%
  summarise(Freq = sum(Freq))
```

You can then chain the output to one of the above to get the plot.

```
%>%
  ggplot() +
  geom_bar(aes(x = Types, y = Freq), 
          stat="identity", fill="blue", colour="black")+
  facet_wrap( ~ Membership)
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can try this solution:

```
library(reshape2)
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)
#Summarise
df2 <- df %>% select(starts_with('Var') | starts_with('Temperature') | starts_with('Member')) %>%
  group_by(Membership) %>% summarise_all(sum,na.rm=T)
#Melt
Melted <- melt(df2,id.vars = 'Membership')
#Plot
ggplot(Melted,aes(x = variable, y = value))+
  geom_bar(stat="identity", fill="blue", colour="black")+
  facet_wrap( ~ Membership)
```

[image]